# LabVIEW How to eliminate a offset value

Tags: offset, labview

In my program I have to read voltage from a electric circuit which is measuring the strain in a object (I know I can read strain directly with DAQ assistant, but the teacher doesn't let me do it). In the beginning, there are no load in the object so the voltage should be zero, but the equipment isn't ideal and there is a offset value. How can I save it to subtract later? I have tried with case structures but it doesn't work.

Here is what I have:

[image]

Comment: Before we look at the offset issue, let's fix your While loop. You've got the stop terminal wired to a value that's being passed in from outside the loop - that means your loop will either execute only once, if that value is True, or forever, if it's False. If you want the loop to either repeat or terminate based on a condition then you need to generate that condition (e.g. read a stop button) *inside* the loop, so that it's recalculated each time round. Try running this VI with execution highlighting turned on (lightbulb icon in the toolbar) to watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the offset using shift registers.

Here you can read about shift registers: http://www.ni.com/getting-started/labview-basics/shift-registers

Comment: Also, consider correcting stop condition of the loop, now you got infinite loop.